# Iframe Not working Phonegap Network Error Occured http://www.digiwebtech.com/Promotion/

Tags: cordova, error-handling, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am having a Phonegap Application( android ) it is simple app its only having an Iframe where it loads a Url

Url is - http://www.digiwebtech.com/Promotion/ 
This Url is working Fine online  But when I give this url as source to iframe it gives the error "Network Error Occured http://www.digiwebtech.com/Promotion/"

For Building This App I am using Online Phonegap Build
build.phonegap.com

I am unable to understand the actual problem in this case all my code is hosted online only iframe is in index.html

Index.html file is working fine on Local Computer

My Index.html Code -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
    Copyright (c) 2012-2014 Adobe Systems Incorporated. All rights reserved.

    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
    or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
    distributed with this work for additional information
    regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
    to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
    "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
    with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
    software distributed under the License is distributed on an
    "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
     KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
    specific language governing permissions and limitations
    under the License.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
         <link href="css/splashstyles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <title>DigiWebTech</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="">

<div class="splash fade-in">
        <h1 class="splash-title fade-in"></h1>
        <a href="#" class="splash-arrow fade-in"><img src="~/assets/img/down-arrow.png" /></a>
    </div>


            <div id="content" style="height: auto; width: auto; overflow: auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;">
        <iframe class="frame" src="http://www.digiwebtech.com/Promotion/" style="position: absolute;min-width:100%;     min-height: 100%; border: none"   >  </iframe>
</div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();

        </script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/assets/js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is It Possible Iframes not Supported By Phonegap . They haven't said they are supported . Whenever I use them it gives error . 
It don't even loads google in iframe

Answer (score 0):

You have to white list URLs which you show in the frame. You have to allow navigation in your config.xml